# Screen goes black

Tags: display

Since 4-5 weeks ago, when playing the screen started to go black every now and then for like 2-3 seconds.
Lately I've been playing Fallout 4, and every day at least 5-6 times it goes full black for a few seconds then comes back. Then I play 6-7 hours without any problem.
This happened maybe once when I was not playing anything, just using windows itself, however if the game starts doing this and I alt-tab out windows will be doing the same a few times.
I always have the latest video card drivers (yes it happened before AMD crimson driver too, maybe more since then).
It's more than annoying, and I don't want to have hardware problems.

My PC:

Windows 10 Professional

Asus R9270 (I never overclock),
FX-6300,
16 Gb DDR3 1866 Mhz,
128 Gb samsung evo ssd,
1 TB Western Digital HDD,
Cooler Master G500 500 W PSU

The rig is a year old.
I keep my PC clean both hardware and software wise ( I clean the parts from dust every 3 months), use Microsoft Defender, Malwarebytes, and CCleaner.
As mentioned before I never overclock, and check the temperature of the card too, never goes above 80 celsius.

Any ideas where to look?

I don't know if this helps I'm using a dell ultrasharp u2412m (1920*1200 resolution) with a dvi port cable.
I bought the monitor 6 months ago, and since then everytime I even slightly move the monitor, the power cable input makes a buzzz sound and the monitor turns off, so I have to correct the position of the end of the cable, but that happens only if I physically move the monitor (of course annoying as well).

Comment: Tried a different monitor?

Comment: Right now I could only check it with a laptop screen.

Comment: Should I try to get a new power cable and dvi cable (since that is a cheap way) to narrow it down?

Comment: Try, but a completely different monitor would rule out the monitor being faulty.

Comment: Is the power cable in correctly? It sounds very much like a loose cable. Especially based on your last line...